# Maven support in Eclipse, pom validate shows wrong errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using newest eclipse. I am very disappointed, after so many years, maven support in eclipse is far from perfect.

here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.codingfarm.fwx</groupId>
    <artifactId>fwx-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>fwx-sea</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>fwx-sea</name>
  <description>Framework X Smart Entity API</description>
  <modules>
    <module>fwx-sea-api</module>
    <module>fwx-sea-impl-mybatis</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

and eclipse complains this:

```
Non-parseable POM /home/ggfan/2-work/fwx-space/fwx-parent/fwx-sea/pom.xml: end tag name </modulefwx> must match start tag name <modules> from line 12 (position: END_TAG seen ...<module></module></modulefwx\n... @14:1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine, I excluded the parent and tried on local. **Cleaning project** probably will fix it.

[image]